# Storage of variables without initializing an object? Ruby Gem 'Mail'

Tags: ruby, class, object, initializer

Working with the [Ruby Gem 'Mail'](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail), I am confused as to how variables are able to be stored without initializing an object?  For example:

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '<username>',
                          :password   => '<password>',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
```

After which you are able to call methods such as `Mail.first` and have it return the first message in the mailbox with the configured defaults.

I realize everything in Ruby is an object, even a class, so when `require 'mail'` is called, does an object containing the the `class Mail` actually get created and mad available to the program?  What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `mail.rb` are loaded into the file that has the `require 'mail'` statement.

After having a look in the gem, `mail.rb` contains the `Mail` module, which in turn contains many other require statements.

**mail.rb**

```
module Mail
  ## skipped for brevity

  # Finally... require all the Mail.methods
  require 'mail/mail'
end
```

**mail/mail.rb**

```
module Mail
  ## skipped for brevity

  # Receive the first email(s) from the default retriever
  # See Mail::Retriever for a complete documentation.
  def self.first(*args, &block)
    retriever_method.first(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

So then the methods are made available to your program.

Comment: Does an object containing the the class Mail actually get created and mad available to the program? What exactly is happening here?  "So mail.rb will contain the mail class and make it available to the current file.", what is the _current file_?  `mail` class, do you mean `Mail`?

Comment: The differences between `load` and `require` are not pertinent to this question...  Can you phrase your answer in the context of a running program.

Comment: Edited answer, if not what your looking for, I don't think I'm understanding the question properly.